# How to get content of sub-controls in WinForm?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, tabcontrol, tabpage

I have WinForm, which have many controls (tabcontrol, tabpage, datagridview,...etc). I want to get data in datagridview. The structure of design is like this (TabControl will have many TabPages, each TabPage will have one TabControl, each TabControl will have many TabPages, each TabPage will have one DataGridView).

```
TabControlX
+TabPage
++TabControl
+++TabPage
++++DataGridView
+++TabPage
++++DataGridView
+TabPage
++TabControl
+++TabPage
++++DataGridView
+++TabPage
++++DataGridView
```

So, I want to get data each DataGridView. I'm not sure if the stuff is correct or bad.

```
            foreach (TabPage tbp in tabControl_X.TabPages)
            {
                foreach (Control item in tbp.Controls)
                {
                    foreach (TabPage sub_tab in item.Controls)
                    {
                        foreach (Control dgv in sub_tab.Controls)
                        {
                            //how to get data dgv?
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To iterate the control hierarchy of the `Form`, make an [iterator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/iterators) method similar to this:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    IEnumerable<Control> IterateControls(Control.ControlCollection controls)
    {
        foreach (Control control in controls) 
        {
            yield return control;
            foreach (Control child in IterateControls(control.Controls))
            { 
                yield return child;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

First, demonstrate the iterator by listing ALL the controls:

```
// Iterate all names
Debug.WriteLine("ALL CONTROLS");
foreach (var control in IterateControls(Controls))
{
    Debug.WriteLine(
        string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(control.Name) ?
            $"Unnamed {control.GetType().Name}"  :
            control.Name);
}
```

[image: list all controls]

*An additional extension indents the output by depth see [Repo](https://github.com/IVSoftware/iterate-controls-of-type.git).*

---

Your question is how about getting just the `DataGridView` controls, so specify `OfType()`

```
// Iterate DataGridView only
Debug.WriteLine("\nDATA GRID VIEW CONTROLS");
foreach (var control in IterateControls(Controls).OfType<DataGridView>())
{
    Debug.WriteLine(control.Name);
}
```

[image: data grid view controls]

Comment: Basically, all DataGridView will be created dynamic through code, not from designers. And i want to get data inside of those and keep it in other place. After that, all DataGridView will be removed at the end.

Comment: There's no reason that controls being created dynamically would have any bearing on whether this works or not. If they're visible, then they're in the control collection. If they're in the control collection, they're discoverable in this manner. Did you try it with your code? Did you run my sample from the [repo](https://github.com/IVSoftware/iterate-controls-of-type.git)?

Comment: I'm not try your repo yet before.I trying debug something in my code and i figure out. Probably I catch up data in DataGridView. Anyway, you really nice for answer my concern. I will be back later from your repo. Tks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the *dgv* control, it must be:

- accessible in the point you need it, in your code
- named as you can find it

So, if you added dgv's through designer of the TabControlX control, then you should be able to access them through thier name.

If you want to access them from outside the TabControlX control, then the dgv's memmbers must be marked as `internal` or `public`.

In addition to the Properties tab in the designer, try to look at the `.Designer.cs` code file; there you should be able to find your control's variables.

Comment: All DataGridView created through code, will not from designers. it's mean all of them will created and after that will removed. I just get data inside of DataGridView after created , and keep that. Finally all of DataGridView will be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative method, using reflection.

This method takes a generic T, constrained to the `Control` class.
Set `T` to the Type of Control you want to find and pass a Control that is the common ancestor (could be your `tabControl_X`).
You could turn it into an extension method.

For example:

```
var childControls = GetAllChildControlsOfType<DataGridView>(tabControl_X);
```

If you pass the Form instance (`this`), you get all child Controls of Type `DataGridView` that have the Form as ancestor, and so on.

Built for .NET 6+, nullable enabled.
If you're targeting .NET Framework, remove all `?` and `!`

```
using System.Reflection;

private ReadOnlyCollection<T> GetAllChildControlsOfType<T>(Control parent) where T : Control {
    var flags = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetField;
    var ctlList = new List<T>();
    var form = parent is Form ? parent : parent.FindForm();
    var childControls = form!.GetType().GetFields(flags).Select(fi => fi.GetValue(form))
                             .Where(obj => obj?.GetType() == typeof(T))
                             .Select(obj => obj as T);

    foreach (T? ctl in childControls) {
        if (HasAncestor(ctl, parent)) {
            ctlList.Add(ctl!);
        }
    }

    bool HasAncestor(Control? ctl, Control? parent) {
        if (ctl is null || parent is null) return false;
        while (ctl.Parent != null) {
            if (ctl.Parent == parent) return true;
            ctl = ctl.Parent;
        }
        return false;
    }
    return new ReadOnlyCollection<T>(ctlList);
}
```